# How to resize a image by it's width and Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: iphone, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to resize or scale a image down by it's width is fixed. I have been searching all over the network, it's about resizing the image to new size by specifying new CGSize value. I only want to scale it down by its width is fixed, like 100px, and the height scale down and Maintain it's Aspect Ratio.

Comment: Can u add some code of what you have tried?

Comment: Calculating the new height, given width and preserving aspect ratio is trivial; just do it. `CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, ceil(newWidth * oldHeight / oldWidth));`

Answer (score 0):

check this out and modify as per your needs.

http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/resize-image-in-iphone-sdk/

Comment: Do I have to specify the target size of height? I only want to set the fixed width of target size. and the height will change automatically for maintaing the aspect ratio.

Comment: It would be useful if your answer here was more than just a link. (It is a good answer otherwise.)